# CURL malformed Json

Tags: php, json, curl

I'm trying to post to an API from my code using CURL. I did a var_dump on my result variable. I got "Malformed JSON" I'm pretty sure my JSON is fine.

The code looks like this:

```
<?php
$postArray = array(
    "Currency" => "EUR",
    "AmountDebit" => 10.00,
    "Invoice" => "testinvoice 123",
    "Services" => array(
        "ServiceList" => array(
            array(
                "Action" => "Pay",
                "Name" => "ideal",
                "Parameters" => array(
                    array(
                        "Name" => "issuer",
                        "Value" => "ABNANL2A"
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
);

ksort($postArray);

$post = json_encode($postArray);

echo $post . '<br><br>';

$md5  = md5($post, true);
$post = base64_encode($md5);

echo '<b>MD5 from json</b> ' . $md5 . '<br><br>';
echo '<b>base64 from MD5</b> ' . $post . '<br><br>';

$websiteKey = 'secret';
$uri        = strtolower(urlencode('testcheckout.buckaroo.nl/json/Transaction'));
$nonce      = 'nonce_' . rand(0000000, 9999999);
$time       = time();

$hmac       = $websiteKey . 'POST' . $uri . $time . $nonce . $post;
$s          = hash_hmac('sha256', $hmac, 'secret', true);
$hmac       = base64_encode($s);
$url= 'https://testcheckout.buckaroo.nl/json/transaction';

echo 'Authorization: hmac ' .$websiteKey.':'.$hmac .':'.$nonce . ':'.$time;


$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Authorization: hmac ' .$websiteKey.':'.$hmac .':'.$nonce . ':'.$time;
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';
$headers[] = 'Content-Length: ' . strlen($post); 


print_r($headers);
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);    
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = curl_exec($curl);

var_dump($result);

curl_close($curl);

?>
```

The response of the $post variable is :

```
{"AmountDebit":10,"Currency":"EUR","Invoice":"testinvoice 123","Services":{"ServiceList":[{"Action":"Pay","Name":"ideal","Parameters":[{"Name":"issuer","Value":"ABNANL2A"}]}]}}
```

Why does var_dump $result return Malformed JSON? I thought it had to do with my header but it doesnt. I googled it but i found no clear answer. So i hope i can find some help here

Apparently i was overwriting the variable i was trying to send. I think im doing it right now and i still get the malformed JSON thing:

```
<?php
$postArray = array(
    "Currency" => "EUR",
    "AmountDebit" => 10.00,
    "Invoice" => "testinvoice 123",
    "Services" => array(
        "ServiceList" => array(
            array(
                "Action" => "Pay",
                "Name" => "ideal",
                "Parameters" => array(
                    array(
                        "Name" => "issuer",
                        "Value" => "ABNANL2A"
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
);

ksort($postArray);

$post = json_encode($postArray);
$post1 = json_encode($postArray);

echo $post . '<br><br>';

$md5  = md5($post, true);
$post = base64_encode($md5);

echo '<b>MD5 from json</b> ' . $md5 . '<br><br>';
echo '<b>base64 from MD5</b> ' . $post . '<br><br>';

$websiteKey = '---';
$uri        = strtolower(urlencode('testcheckout.buckaroo.nl/json/Transaction'));
$nonce      = 'nonce_' . rand(0000000, 9999999);
$time       = time();

$hmac       = $websiteKey . 'POST' . $uri . $time . $nonce . $post;
$s          = hash_hmac('sha256', $hmac, '----', true);
$hmac       = base64_encode($s);
$url= 'https://testcheckout.buckaroo.nl/json/transaction';

echo 'Authorization: hmac ' .$websiteKey.':'.$hmac .':'.$nonce . ':'.$time;


$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Authorization: hmac ' .$websiteKey.':'.$hmac .':'.$nonce . ':'.$time;
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';
$headers[] = 'Content-Length: ' . strlen($post1); 


print_r($headers);
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);    
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = curl_exec($curl);

var_dump($result);

curl_close($curl);

?>
```

Comment: You are overwriting the `$post` variable.

Comment: @RolandStarke same thing still, look at my updated code in my question.